# How to make working: FOREIGN KEY error during addition

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl

I have two tables, `books` and `borrowing requests` - I am making a study project to learn MySQL. Trying to link these two tables using a FK, and constantly get an error:

```
 "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")
```

Apart from documentation, I searched virtually all of the related topics here on SO, however, no success. Types are the same, columns both unsigned, one primary key, etc. - to my understanding I have respected all of the provisions. But it does not work! What am I missing?

Here are the two tables and the fk addition query:

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `book_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `book_title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `author_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
  `book_condition` INT(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23453 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `borrowing_requests` (
  `request_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `due_date` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23453 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

FK Query:

```
ALTER TABLE `books` ADD CONSTRAINT books_fk FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) 
REFERENCES `borrowing_requests`(`book_id`) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the foreign key "backwards" - the borrowing request should reference a book, not the other way round:

```
ALTER TABLE `borrowing_requests` ADD CONSTRAINT books_fk FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) 
REFERENCES `books`(`book_id`) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Comment: Hm, thank you, it works. Looks like I still am quite far from understanding the FK concept, will go to learn :)